# xgamma -display parameter for dual monitor setup

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I want to change gamma for my first monitor. Every time I invoke xgamma with different `-display` parameters it somehow points to my **second** monitor. But I want to modify **first** one.

I tried these commands.

The parameters I have used for `-display` are `:0`, `:0.0`, `:0.1`, `:1.0`, `:1.1`, `:1`. Only the first 2 works. But it points to my second monitor. Not the first one. Here is a shell script to test it.

```
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :0
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :0.0
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :0.1
xgamma:  unable to open display ':0.1'
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :1.0
xgamma:  unable to open display ':1.0'
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :1.1
xgamma:  unable to open display ':1.1'
shiplu@KubuntuD:~$ xgamma -display :1
xgamma:  unable to open display ':1'
```

How can I change the gamma for the first/primary monitor?

Answer (score 12):

I have same problem with `xgamma`, you can use `xrandr` to do that

my first monitor:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1360x768 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal --gamma 1.000:1.000:1.000
```

my second monitor:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --pos 0x768 --rotate normal --gamma 1.100:1.000:1.000
```

the --gamma parameter works in same way that xgamma

```
--gamma R:G:B 
xrandr --output (some monitor) --gamma 1:1:1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am currently using xrandr to setup my dual-montior setup.

Answer (score 9):

To see a list of connected displays by name...

```
$ xrandr --current |grep connected |grep -v disconnected
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 290mm
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 880mm x 490mm
```

Set the gamma, specifying one of the connected displays as follows...

```
xrandr --current --output HDMI1 --gamma 0.5:0.5:0.5
```

Note: Using `--current` is not required -- it just speeds things up.

Comment: `--current` speeds up `xrandr` ten-fold.